# Html with javascript into qualtrics survey

Tags: javascript, html, survey, qualtrics

I'm a student of University of Bologna (Italy)

I created a simple game using html and javascript. The goal is reaching the end of a path using the arrow keys on the keyboard as quickly as possible.

I would insert this game into a Qualtrics survey.
I have tried to  entered the html both in the html tab and in the source tab of the Rich Content Editor but the result is the same: when I use preview question I see the right template but of course I can't test the javascript script and when I use preview survey I don't see the right template, only some text.

I'm wondering if I should use "add javascript", I haven't a javascript script but html with javascript inside.

Thanks for your help. Federico

The script works, see http://federicoforte.altervista.org/testDestra.html

and here there is the code:

```
<html>
<head><title>Un piccolo gioco</title>

<STYLE type=text/css>#board TD {
FONT-SIZE: 2pt; WIDTH: 30pt; HEIGHT: 30pt
}
TD.foot {
FONT-SIZE: 10pt
}
#board TD.start {
BORDER-TOP: black 2px solid; FONT-SIZE: 8pt; BACKGROUND: white; BORDER-LEFT: black 2px solid; COLOR: red; TEXT-ALIGN: center; 
}
#board TD.end {
FONT-SIZE: 8pt; COLOR: green; TEXT-ALIGN: center
}
#messaggio {
PADDING-RIGHT: 0pt; PADDING-LEFT: 0pt; PADDING-BOTTOM: 0pt; MARGIN: 0pt; PADDING-TOP: 0pt; TEXT-ALIGN: center
}
</style>

<script language=JavaScript>
var percorso = new Array()
for (var righe = 0; righe < 13; righe++)
    percorso[righe]= new Array()

percorso[0][0] = new Array(1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
percorso[1][0] = new Array(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
percorso[2][0] = new Array(0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0)
percorso[3][0] = new Array(0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0)
percorso[4][0] = new Array(0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1)
percorso[5][0] = new Array(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
percorso[6][0] = new Array(0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0,0)
percorso[7][0] = new Array(0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,0)
percorso[8][0] = new Array(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
percorso[9][0] = new Array(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0)
percorso[10][0] =new Array(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,0)
percorso[11][0] =new Array(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
percorso[12][0] =new Array(0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)

percorso[0][1] = new Array(1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
percorso[1][1] = new Array(1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
percorso[2][1] = new Array(1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0)
percorso[3][1] = new Array(1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0)
percorso[4][1] = new Array(1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,1)
percorso[5][1] = new Array(1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1)
percorso[6][1] = new Array(1,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1)
percorso[7][1] = new Array(1,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1)
percorso[8][1] = new Array(1,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1)
percorso[9][1] = new Array(1,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,1)
percorso[10][1] = new Array(1,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1)
percorso[11][1] = new Array(1,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1)
percorso[12][1] = new Array(0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1)

var lati = new Array("border-top","border-right")
var t0=0
var t1=0
var errori=0

function avanza(){

if (!dentro) return
    if (coordRiga==0 && coordCol==0)
        t0=performance.now()
    switch (event.keyCode)  {
    case 37: //sinistra
        if (percorso[coordRiga][1][coordCol-1]==0)      {
            if (prosegui(board.rows[coordRiga].cells[coordCol-1]))
                messaggio.innerText="Sinistra"
            coordCol--
        document.all.board.rows[coordRiga].cells[coordCol].style.backgroundColor ="green"
        } else {
        messaggio.innerText="Attento, hai sbagliato percorso"
        errori++ }
        break;
    case 38: //su
    if (percorso[coordRiga][0][coordCol]==0)    {
        if (prosegui(board.rows[coordRiga-1].cells[coordCol]))
            messaggio.innerText="Su"
            coordRiga--
            document.all.board.rows[coordRiga].cells[coordCol].style.backgroundColor ="green"
    } else      {
        messaggio.innerText="Attento, hai sbagliato percorso"
        errori++ }
        break;
    case 39: //destra
    if (percorso[coordRiga][1][coordCol]==0)    {
        if (prosegui(board.rows[coordRiga].cells[coordCol+1]))
            messaggio.innerText="Destra"
            coordCol++
    document.all.board.rows[coordRiga].cells[coordCol].style.backgroundColor ="green"
    } else      {
        messaggio.innerText="Attento, hai sbagliato percorso"
        errori++ }
        break;  
    case 40: //giù
    if (percorso[coordRiga+1]==null) {
    errori++ 
    messaggio.innerText="Attento, hai sbagliato percorso"
    return }
    if (percorso[coordRiga+1][0][coordCol]==0)
    {
        if (prosegui(board.rows[coordRiga+1].cells[coordCol]))
            messaggio.innerText="Giù"
        coordRiga++
    document.all.board.rows[coordRiga].cells[coordCol].style.backgroundColor ="green"
    } else      {
        messaggio.innerText="Attento, hai sbagliato percorso"
        errori++ }
        break;
    }
    if (document.all.board.rows[coordRiga].cells[coordCol].innerText=="end") {
        t1=performance.now()
        messaggio.innerText = "Molto bene, hai completato il percorso!\n "+"Hai impiegato: "+ (t1-t0)/1000+" secondi"+" con " +errori+ " errori."
        dentro=false
        stop=true
    }
}

function prosegui(casella) {
if ((board.rows[coordRiga].cells[coordCol].style.backgroundColor =="green") && (casella.style.backgroundColor=='green')) {
            messaggio.innerText="Stai tornando indietro"
            errori++
            board.rows[coordRiga].cells[coordCol].style.backgroundColor =""
            return false
            }
            return true
}

</script>
</head>

<body bgColor="white">
<br>
<center>
<b>TEST di abilit&aacute; con la mano DESTRA</b>
<br>
Usa i tasti freccia per completare il percorso nel <b>minor tempo possibile</b>, attento per&ograve;  a non sbagliare scontrandoti con le pareti del percorso.
<br>Saranno memorizzati anche gli errori. </strong></p>
<br><p>
<TABLE id=board cellSpacing=0 cellPadding=0 align=center>
<script>
for (var riga = 0; riga<percorso.length; riga++) {
document.write("<TR>") 
for (var col = 0; col<percorso[riga][0].length; col++) {
document.write("<TD STYLE='")
for (var cell = 0; cell<2; cell++) {
if (percorso[riga][cell][col]==1) 
document.write(lati[cell]+": 2px black solid;")
}
if ((0==col) && (0!=riga))
document.write("border-left: 2px black solid;")
if (riga==percorso.length-1)
document.write("border-bottom: 2px black solid;")
if (riga==percorso.length-1 && col>=4 && col<11)
document.write("border-bottom: 2px white solid;")
if ((0==riga) && (0==col)) 
document.write(" background-color:yellow;' class=start>start</TD>")
else
if ((riga==percorso.length-1) && (col==percorso[riga][0].length-1))
document.write("' class=end>end</TD>")
else
document.write("'> </TD>")
}
document.write("</TR>")
}
coordRiga = 0
coordCol = 0
dentro = true
document.onkeydown=avanza;


</script>
</table>
<p id=messaggio></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Qualtrics'support told me that it could be a JFE combatibility problem, is it possible?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Maybe try... embedding it? Please give the code.

Comment: I have edited the question adding the code, thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

You should run script after page is loaded. If you can share code, I can give a try.

Comment: This is a comment not an answer.

Comment: I have edited the question adding the code, thanks for help

Comment: Please close the "head" tag and code should work. I just checked and It work fine for me.  Copy the code in "HTML view" section of a "Descriptive type" question( though this is not the standard way).